# Función de salida en c#

Tags: c#, funciones

veréis estoy con un programa para clase, en el que se le presentan varias opciones al usuario, y después de cada una, el programa le pide si quiere continuar o no, y no consigo acabar de hacerlo, éste es el código que tengo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication46
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] array = new int[10];
            int opcio = 0;
            char final = ' ';
            bool acabar = false;

            while (!acabar)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                opcio = menuPrincipal();
                switch (opcio)
                {
                    case 1:
                        suma();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        resta();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        multiplicacio();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        divisio();
                        break;
                    case 5:

                        break;
                }




                final = espera();

                if (final == 'n')
                {
                    acabar = true;
                }

            }
        }


        static void suma()
        {
            int numero1, numero2;

            Console.WriteLine("entra un nombre");
            numero1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.WriteLine("entra un segon nombre");
            numero2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



            Console.WriteLine("La suma dels nombres és "+ (numero1 + numero2));

        }


        static void resta()
        {
            int numero1, numero2;

            Console.WriteLine("entra un nombre");
            numero1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.WriteLine("entra un segon nombre");
            numero2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



            Console.WriteLine("La resta dels nombres és "+ (numero1 - numero2));


        }



        static void multiplicacio()
        {
            int numero1, numero2;

            Console.WriteLine("entra un nombre");
            numero1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.WriteLine("entra un segon nombre");
            numero2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



            Console.WriteLine("La multiplicació dels nombres és "+ (numero1 * numero2));


        }

        static void divisio()
        {
            int numero1, numero2;

            Console.WriteLine("entra un nombre");
            numero1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.WriteLine("entra un segon nombre");
            numero2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



            Console.WriteLine("La divisió dels nombres és "+ (numero1 / numero2));


        }


        public static int menuPrincipal()
        {
            int opcio = 0;
            bool entradaValida = false;
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

            escriureMenu();

            do
            {
                cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (Char.IsNumber(cki.KeyChar))
                {
                    opcio = Int32.Parse(cki.KeyChar.ToString());

                    if (opcio > 5 || opcio < 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("El nombre ha d'estar entre 1 i 5, torna a provar");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        entradaValida = true;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    opcio = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("La opció ha de ser un nombre, torna a provar");
                }

            } while (!entradaValida);
            return opcio;
        }
        public static void escriureMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Operacions aritmètiques");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - suma");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - resta");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - multiplicació");
            Console.WriteLine("4 - Divisió");
            Console.WriteLine("5 - Sortir");
        }


        static char espera()
        {
            char opcio;
            bool entradaValida = false;

            Console.WriteLine("vols continuar? s/n");
            do
            {
                opcio = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

                if (opcio != 's' || opcio != 'n')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("La opció només pot ser s o n, en minúscules");
                }
                else
                {
                    entradaValida = true;
                }
            } while (opcio != 'n' || opcio != 's');

            return opcio;

        }



    }
}
```

El principal problema lo tengo aquí:

```
 static char espera()
        {
            char opcio;
            bool entradaValida = false;

            Console.WriteLine("vols continuar? s/n");
            do
            {
                opcio = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

                if (opcio != 's' || opcio != 'n')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("La opció només pot ser s o n, en minúscules");
                }
                else
                {
                    entradaValida = true;
                }
            } while (opcio != 'n' || opcio != 's');

            return opcio;

        }
```

Ya que el programa sólo me dice que sólo admite n o s independientemente de qué le introduzca, alguna ayuda?

Comment: Cuál es el problema que tienes? No termino de entenderlo.

Comment: La función de salida, el segundo fragmento de código, me pide siempre que el único valor que admite es 'n' o 's', aunque le meta esos valores. Lo que tiene que hacer es, si pones 's', el programa continúa y te devuelve al menú principal, si no, te saca del programa, y estoy atascado ahí

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes al verificar la respuesta del usuario aquí:

```
static char espera()
{
    char opcio;
    bool entradaValida = false;

    Console.WriteLine("vols continuar? s/n");
    do
    {
        opcio = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

        if (opcio != 's' || opcio != 'n')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("La opció només pot ser s o n, en minúscules");
        }
        else
        {
            entradaValida = true;
        }
    } while (opcio != 'n' || opcio != 's');

    return opcio;

}
```

Estás utilizando el comparador `||` cuando debería ser `&&` quedando así:

```
static char espera()
{
    char opcio;
    bool entradaValida = false;

    Console.WriteLine("vols continuar? s/n");
    do
    {
        opcio = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

        if (opcio != 's' && opcio != 'n')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("La opció només pot ser s o n, en minúscules");
        }
        else
        {
            entradaValida = true;
        }
    } while (opcio != 'n' && opcio != 's');

    return opcio;

}
```